# Oracle JInitiator version too low

Tags: oracle, jinitiator

When I Open a page in my intranet portal, I get a window with the following message

> FRM - 92095: Oracle JInitiator version too low.
>   Please install version 1.1.8.2 or higher

I have installed JInitiator 1.1.8.16 and JInitiator 1.3.1.30. But I get the same error message.

Any solution to this???

Comment: uninstall jInitiator 1.1.8.16

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't uninstall anything !

You can use Java7 in Windows or Mac

In Control Panel of Java

click Java
click view
in version7 Parameters write:

-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."

It works !

Comment: This didn't work for me. Java panel shows 1.7.0_60 and 1.6.0_45. They both have the -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."  parameter. The oracle form still returns the FRM 92095 error message.

Answer (score 7):

Unninstall Java Update 7. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Do you happen to have JRE 1.7 installed on your pc ? In that case, uninstall it and install the JRE 1.6 again.

```
> Note: ID 1348436.1    and a bug exists ( not yet fixed )
> Bug:11782681 APPS6: FORMS DO NOT LAUNCH WITH BETA JRE 1.7
```

Comment: what java version do you have installed on your pc?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall Java 7 and install Java 6.

This forum from shows the details:

http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/frm-92095-oracle-jinitiator-version-too-low-disable-jre-1-7-auto-update-for-all-e-business-suite-and-oracle-forms-end-users/

Comment: That website is **not** affiliated with Oracle. I quote [this page](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/about/): "Please note : The material provided on this blog does not come from Oracle and is not supported by Oracle"

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in Windows 7. I went to the control panel and clicked "Java (32-bit)". A window pops up called "Java control panel", I clicked the "Java" tab and the "view" button. A window pops up called "Java Runtime Environment Settings". On the user tab in my system I have two versions installed: Platform 1.6 and platform 1.7, I unticked the "enable" tick-box on Platform 1.7 and clicked "OK". I restarted my browser and was able to access the oracle forms. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had jdk 1.7.. due to this i was getting the error. Now I installed jdk 1.6 from http://www.java.com/en/download/manual_v6.jsp. and followd as above "I went to the control panel and clicked "Java (32-bit)". A window pops up called "Java control panel", I clicked the "Java" tab and the "view" button. A window pops up called "Java Runtime Environment Settings". On the user tab in my system I have two versions installed: Platform 1.6 and platform 1.7, I unticked the "enable" tick-box on Platform 1.7 and clicked "OK". I restarted my browser and was able to access the oracle forms"

And it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

4years pasted,a same problem occured in china with mac air:
A lot answers for windows system,I'm offering a methond to all system include OSX,if you can open the windows in my attacment.

enter **`-Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."`**  as picture shows

[image: configur java profile]

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by, no kidding, using Netscape